# How to add a container to a docker stack during runtime?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a main image that manages extra apps (similar to what portainer does)
Now I want to handle teardown gracefully.

Can I add a container I spawned during runtime, add to the stack, so when the stack is restarted or stopped, all the other containers are also stopped?

I have the problem right now during development, that I spawn a new container and often that container already exists